# Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@net/rest/RequestHandler'

Tags: typescript

Today when I build my typescript project, shows error like this:

```
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@net/rest/RequestHandler' in '/Users/xiaoqiangjiang/source/reddwarf/frontend/ai-web/node_modules/js-wheel/dist'
```

then I checked the js file that compile from ts file, the path did not replaced. it still look like this after using `yarn ttsc` command to convert to js:

```
import { LoginType } from "@model/enumn/LoginType";
import { WheelGlobal } from "@model/immutable/WheelGlobal";
import LocalStorage from "@utils/data/LocalStorage";
import DeviceHandler from "@utils/data/DeviceHandler";
```

I have already add the lib `typescript-transform-paths` and config in tsconfig.json like this:

```
"plugins": [
      // Transform paths in output .js files
      { "transform": "typescript-transform-paths" },
      { "transform": "ts-transformer-keys/transformer" },

      // Transform paths in output .d.ts files (Include this line if you output declarations files)
      { "transform": "typescript-transform-paths", "afterDeclarations": true }
    ]
```

what should I do to replace the @ path to the path like `../foo/bar`? is there any simple way to convert to path? BTW, this is my tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": { 
    /* Language and Environment */
    "target": "es5",                                  /* Set the JavaScript language version for emitted JavaScript and include compatible library declarations. */
    
    /* Modules */
    "module": "esnext",                                /* Specify what module code is generated. */
    
    /* Emit */
    "declaration": true,                              /* Generate .d.ts files from TypeScript and JavaScript files in your project. */
    "outDir": "./dist", 
    "lib": [ "DOM","ES2015" ], 
    "esModuleInterop": true, 
    "moduleResolution":"node",                            /* Emit additional JavaScript to ease support for importing CommonJS modules. This enables `allowSyntheticDefaultImports` for type compatibility. */
    // "preserveSymlinks": true,                         /* Disable resolving symlinks to their realpath. This correlates to the same flag in node. */
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,            /* Ensure that casing is correct in imports. */

    /* Type Checking */
    "strict": true,                                      /* Enable all strict type-checking options. */
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "baseUrl": "src",
    "paths": {
      "@net/*":["net/*"],
      "@auth/*":["auth/*"],
      "@utils/*":["utils/*"],
      "@model/*":["model/*"],
    },
    // Note: To transform paths for both the output .js and .d.ts files, you need both of the below entries
    "plugins": [
      // Transform paths in output .js files
      { "transform": "typescript-transform-paths" },
      { "transform": "ts-transformer-keys/transformer" },

      // Transform paths in output .d.ts files (Include this line if you output declarations files)
      { "transform": "typescript-transform-paths", "afterDeclarations": true }
    ]                                 
  },
  "exclude": [
    "dist"
  ]
}
```